# Disable LDAP service in CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, ldap, command-line-interface, dhcp

What command needed to disable LDAP service in CentOS 6.3.
I tried:

```
authconfig --disableldap
```

but it doesn't work.

I am trying to run `ISC-DHCP` in my machine but it always shows

> Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were
>   not specified in the config file.

So I tried to disable LDAP which I never installed, any Idea?

***Edit:***
These are my steps I made for installing ISC-DHCP:

```
#yum install dhcp

#cp /usr/share/doc/dhcp*/dhcp.conf.sample /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

and when I tried:

```
#/etc/rc.d/init.d/dhcp start
```

I got: `FAILED`

Then I used:

```
#dhcpd -t
```

I got:

> Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were
>   not specified in the config file.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and/or verify that ldap entries have been removed?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify if you are using OpenLDAP or 389, so I'm assuming the latter, which is the standard in RHEL/CentOS/Fedora. You need to issue the following commands as root, or using sudo:

```
 # service dirsrv stop
 # chkconfig dirsrv off
```

You still need to adjust other configuration items like `/etc/nsswitch.conf` if you have been using LDAP to resolve any of the databases listed in there.

In the event that Pluggable Authentication Modules(PAM) are being used PAM will also need to be configured to stop using LDAP.  This can be done using

```
pam-config -d --ldap
```

That in addition to the previously mentioned changes will disable LDAP authentication.

Comment: it doesn't recognize `dirsrv`. actually I am trying to run ISC-DHCP in my machine but it always shows `Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file.
` So I tried to disable LDAP which I never installed, any Idea?

Comment: You definitely should have mention these bits in the original question, care to edit it? It'd provide context for other people reading your question.

Comment: I have added them.

Comment: I did not find `dhcp-ldap`, where it can be found?

Comment: There used to be one in CentOS 5. Does the reading of /usr/share/doc/dhcp-$ver/README.ldap help? have you modified the dhcp configuration? if yes, how? dhcp should not be querying LDAP unless configured to do so.

Comment: I added my steps I used to install ISC-DHCP.